# NGINX Proxy pass keep wrong redirect port

Tags: nginx, proxypass

First, would like to apologize to post this. I am already searching this issue, try and error but still didn't get answers. Please dont mad at me.

Ok here is my single config file:

```
upstream app-backend {
        server 172.23.2.143:9080 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10s;
        server 172.23.2.144:9080 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10s;
}

server {
    listen 12001 ssl;
    server_name test.abc.com;
    error_page  497 https://test.abc.com:12001$request_uri;
    include /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/tls/ssl.conf;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app-backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
      }
}
```

So the problem is,
when i access my main domain which is and do some login (POST) : 
`https://test.abc.com:12001/login.jsp` which is will redirect to one of the upstream with same path,

it throw me to `http://test.abc.com:9080/home.detail` which is this site
did not exist and i get message on browser `this site cannot be reached`

The question is, why this redirect to port 9080 which is belongs to backend port. i dont know what to do anymore. i just really need help and direction. Please

Comment: This is not from nginx, it is from your web application.

Comment: thank you very much @MichaelHampton for your suggest. let me check with the third party, yess our backend is third party.. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am solving above case with this configuration.

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/NGINX_cache/ keys_zone=backcache:10m;

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}


upstream app-backend {
       ip_hash;
       server 172.22.8.143:9080 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10s;
       server 172.22.8.144:9080 weight=1 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=10s;
}

server {
    listen 9080 ssl;
    server_name test.abc.com;
    error_page  497 https://test.abc.com:9080$request_uri;
    include /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/tls/ssl.conf;


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app-backend;
        proxy_set_header   Host  $http_host;
        proxy_cache backcache;
      }

}
```